# Make function more re-usable

Tags: jquery

I need to run a function that makes checkboxes behave like radio buttons. I know, long story. Anyway, I want to make it more re-usable and not have to rewrite it for each group. I have it working like this:

```
$(function() {
    var $apples = $('input.apples');
    $apples.click(function() {
        $apples.removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

How can I make this more global so that if I have another group of checkboxes .bannanas it will work for them as well without having to rewrite it?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a plugin:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YbGtE/2/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.makeRadios = function() {
        var $items = this;
        return this.click(function() {
            $items.removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        });
    };
})( jQuery );

$('input.apples').makeRadios();
$('input.bananas').makeRadios();
```

---

**EDIT:** As requested in the comment below, to uncheck a checkbox on a double click, do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YbGtE/3/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.makeRadios = function() {
        var $items = this;
        return this.click(function() {
            $items.removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        }).dblclick(function() {
            $items.removeAttr('checked');
        });
    };
})( jQuery );

$('input.apples').makeRadios();
$('input.bananas').makeRadios();
```

Comment: How can you make "double clicking" a check box un check it combined with this?

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design: Add `.dblclick(function({$items.removeAttr('checked');});` after the `.click()` call. http://jsfiddle.net/YbGtE/3/ I updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector:

```
'input:checkbox'
```

Or, if only certain checkboxes should be changed, add a class to the selector:

```
'input:checkbox.makeRadio'
```

And add that class to the checkboxes you want changed.

Comment: Sorry, "global" was the wrong word. It should have read "re-usable"will this un check an "apple" checkbox if you check a "bannana" checkbox? I need to keep the two groups separate.

Comment: Use his second example and add a class `makeRadio` to all the checkboxes you want to to act like radios.

Comment: They need to have this behavior only with thier group or class. Checking one from "apples" shouldn't uncheck one from "bannanas" it will if they have the same class,right?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that each group of checkboxes has the same `class` attribute you could automate it with:

```
$(function() {
    var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox.asRadio');
    checkboxes.click(function() {
        var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
        checkboxes.each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('class') == myClass) $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        });
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Where the checkboxes you want to behave as radio fields have the 'asRadio' class as well.